# python - selenium webdriver wait until condition met

Tags: python, if-statement, selenium-webdriver, conditional-statements

i want to make the selenium webdriver to click something when the condition met, and to refresh the page if the condition not met, is this the right code for the condition met or not? i need enlightenment, because this code isn't executed properly

```
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait_new = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'create_it'))
wait_old = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'submit_it'))
if wait_new:
    time.sleep(1)
    item = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'create_it')
    item.click()
    time.sleep(2)
elif wait_old:
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.refresh()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the wait in a `try...except` statement and catch the `TimeoutException` should the finding of the element fail. And try to use the built in expected conditions

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
try:
    #elem = wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'create_it'))
    elem = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'create_it')))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'end'});", elem)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(elem)).click()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.refresh()
```

Follow same process for the `submit_it` element

Comment: so for the proccess of "submit_it" is the same? i make another try and except?

Comment: Yeah. That's the basic criterion of using explicit waits: set a timeout, pass in a condition, wait for it to be fulfilled within the set time or catch when it doesn't.

Comment: well i try to add another try and except, but both of it is running (i put print(something) on both code).

Comment: What do you mean both of it is running?

Comment: ah never mind, i tweak my code a little bit, give if condition inside try and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

From your code above, it seems that you're waiting for an element to be present before clicking it. For use cases like this, Selenium provides explicit waits, for instance:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "create_it")))
```

This piece of code will keep trying to locate the element every 500 ms, until it times out (10 seconds).

Comment: so if the condition met, i just need to write code to do what i want to achieve?

Comment: Somewhat yes. This is a pointer to where you can possibly start to think and structure your approach.